# Choice field which allow multiple selection, is not showing inside the "Filter field" inside the "PnP - Search Filters"

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp-search-webparts

We have a SharePoint list column named "category", as follow:-

[image]

and it has a managed property & crawl property, as follow:-

[image]

but inside the "PnP - Search Filters" web part this managed property is not showing inside the "Filter Field" any advice?, as follow:-

[image]

This is the web part which we are using https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There might be 2 parts to your problem:
I had similar issue. After adding the property it wasn´t showing. I have triggered a site re-crawl (Site Settings--> Search and offline...--> Re-crawl this site) and I got the property (the automated one)

Here is second part of your issue, in SharePoint Online For a property to be viable refiner your need to map it to one of the RefinableStringsXX pre-created Managed Properties (again trigger re-crawl) and use this in your filter

Please note that depending on size of your site it can take up to 24 hours for index to be fully updated.